# Stalls Booting Into Recovery Mode

Tags: recovery-mode

So I just received a second hand nvidia system running Ubuntu. No clue about logins so I tried to boot into recovery mode but every time I select the option to it gets stuck booting on one line everytime.

> systemd-journald[1208]: Recieved client request to flush runtime journal.

Any suggestions? (I’m fairly new to Ubuntu)

Comment: If you purchased it second hand, I would recommend reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: It is ten times easier than trying to make repairs from the recovery mode console. For one thing, a reinstall will remove the errors, and you won't have to do anything extra.